# Using "wall" in Facebook App Name

Tags: facebook

I am consistently getting a "failed" message when trying to create a Facebook App with the word "wall" in it. I have tried multiple combinations such as:

1. "The Someword Wall"
2. "SomewordWall"
3. "Somewordwall"
4. "The Somewordwall App"
5. etc...

Is "wall" a banned word that cannot be used in the Facebook app name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the word "wall" is indeed a banned word. Facebook platform app names must conform to the Advertising Name Policy. Below is an excerpt from their Advertising Regulations regarding names relevant to your problem.

"Ads may not imply a Facebook endorsement or partnership of any kind. Ads linking to Facebook branded content (including Pages, groups, events, or Connect sites) may make limited reference to "Facebook" in ad text for the purpose of clarifying the destination of the ad. All other ads and landing pages may not use our copyrights or trademarks (including Facebook, the Facebook and F Logos, FB, Face, Poke, Book, and Wall) or any confusingly similar marks, except as expressly permitted by our Brand Usage Guidelines or with our prior written permission."